# Increment the date by 1 hour

Tags: mysql, dateadd

I selected a date value from a table.But I can't increment the hours by 1.

Select dateadd(hh,1,min(date)) from table1;

I keep getting error as date add not found

Comment: try: **select `date`+ interval 1 hour from table1;**

Comment: `dateadd` not found, because the function is named [`date_add`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), note the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

```
select date_add(hh, interval 1 hour) from table1;
```